# Word for someone who when leaving a room makes it feel like someone has entered

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the following:-

"When they left the room, it was as if someone else entered".

I vaguely recall reading a Yiddish term that described this in a novel many years ago, but all I can find is Nephesh  - soul.

Comment: A relevant phrase here may be "[addition by subtraction](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Addition+by+subtraction)."

Comment: Yes, but an it be a little more personal?

Comment: ... You can talk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest I can think of (and it's not Yiddish):

- Conspicuous by his/her absence

see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/conspicuous+by+absence

Comment: Ta. It's on those lines, but this term had 'feeling' to it - as if the temperature had changed.

Answer (score 2):

The Yiddish word you're referring to is **Nebbish**:

> a timid, meek, or ineffectual person - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nebbish)

Possible alternatives: **Complete Non-entity**, **Oxygen-thief**.

Comment: Nebbish could be possible, although something (perhaps a false memory after all these years) suggests a two-word term. Oxygen-thief seems a bit crude for what I'm after - is there something more elegant, that reflects a change in temperature, if you will?

Comment: "Nebbish" is the canonical answer, with OP's description appearing almost verbatim in the book "The Joys of Yiddish"